# How to redirect to a page which exists in specif project to another page in other project in the same solution?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have windows phone solution ; which contain two c# projects.
I have a button in one in the pages in the first project ; which we redirect the user to another page in the second solution.
How to redirect to a page which exists in specif project to another page in other project in the same solution ?
since we use the following code to redirect between the pages in the same project.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referencing the other project, you can use the following method:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/YourOtherProjectName;component/TargetPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

EDIT:
If anyone is interested, I've put a sample project on Github: https://github.com/tpetrina/blogcode/tree/master/BlogResearch. WP7 application project is called **NavigateToLibraryPage** and it contains a single button that navigates to the page in the referenced class library named **wp7.library**

Comment: What is the component ? is it a key word ?

Comment: Yes it is. This is standard URI notation.

Comment: I write the following :

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewsFeed;component/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

The exception is :

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

Comment: I reference it and the redirect to the page in the second app.
but when I click on a button in the page I redirect to it ; it's give exception. Even the code before put it in the solution was run correctly

Comment: I see it. and the redirect is working with me. my problem now is not in the redirect. when I redirect from project A to B ; project B don't work after I redirect to it. but If I run it as sperated project it's work well. In other words ; my project functionality doesn't work work after I redirect it from another project.

Comment: You mean from one application to another? Instead of from one application to class library.

Comment: Yes. from application to another application

Comment: This can only be done on windows phone 8 using URI associations. Take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx.