# windows phone, instantiate a page and show it

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to instantiate a `PhoneApplicationPage` from another project (in the same solution, but this shouldn't be important, should it?) and show it?

Well, I know that it is possible to instantiate another page with:

```
MyPageInProjectB bPage= new MyPageInProjectB ();
```

but how do I show it?

I want to do the following:
I have two projects, and I want to show a page of one project within the other project and passing data between them. So I thought this would be perfect:

```
public partial class MyPageInProjectA : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private MyPageInProjectB bPage;

    public MyPageInProjectA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyComplexObject objectIWantToPassToOtherPage = new MyComplexObject ();

        bPage= new MyPageInProjectB (objectIWantToPassToOtherPage);
    }

    private void ShowBPageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this is now what I want to do, but what doesn't work
        bPage.Show();
    }
}
```

Or is there another way to pass complex data between those pages?

I don't want to use query strings, because it happens sometimes, that the (De-)Serializer has problems with `MyComplexObject`.

I read how to navigate between both pages in this thread: [How to redirect to a page which exists in specif project to another page in other project in the same solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506731/how-to-redirect-to-a-page-which-exists-in-specif-project-to-another-page-in-othe) 
but I want to pass a complex object from one page to another. How can I do that?

Comment: Are both projects windows phone app projects?

Comment: At this Point: no. Project A is a Windows phone app, and the other one (`ProjectB`) is a class library. But I can change this, if it would be better.

Comment: Hmm @Rico-E you need to use Navigate, as Alaa's answer specified. `.Show()` won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass non-string parameters between pages in windows phone 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654379/how-do-i-pass-non-string-parameters-between-pages-in-windows-phone-8)

Comment: @PaulAnnetts I know that `.Show()` won't work, as this method does not exist, it should only clarify what I want to do. The problem with `Navigate` is, that I can not give an object as Parameter, can I? I am wondering if I can get the xaml behind the `bPage`-object, and show that. Is it possible?

Comment: @PaulAnnetts Thank you for pointing me to the other thread. It helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Edit:
Ok, now after reading your question carefully I can give you a better answer.***

First, you cannot pass data to a page constructor since the runtime itself handles instance creation when navigating and you can only navigate using `NavigationService`. However, you have other options.

One of them is using query string but if you don't want to use that you could use `PhoneApplicationService` to store your complex object and have the other page read from it.

```cs
// In source page
MyComplexObject objectIWantToPassToOtherPage = new MyComplexObject ();
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["MyComplexObject"] = objectIWantToPassToOtherPage;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ProjectB;component/MyPageInProjectB.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

// In destination page's constructor
public MyPageInProjectB() {
  var myComplexObject = (MyComplexObject) PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["MyComplexObject"];
  // ...
}
```

Other than that is using global variables. These are the only options I can think of.

---

To navigate to the page in your class library `ProjectB` you need to use a uri similar to the following:

`/{assemblyName};component/{path}`

In your case, you can do the following:

`NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ProjectB;component/MyPageInProjectB.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`

Note that I am specifying relative path here so `MyPageInProjectB.xaml` needs to be in the root folder inside `ProjectB` for the above example to work.

Comment: Sorry, but this is actually NO answer. I want to pass an object between both pages. Navigation itself is no problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! This seems to me as if this is a very good solution. In an abstract way it is very similar to that  way in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654379/how-do-i-pass-non-string-parameters-between-pages-in-windows-phone-8 . I will give it a try. Thank you very much!