# Redirect to another page in different project of same solution

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

So I made a WP8 app and I split them into separate projects, and I put a button that redirects to another app's page but the other page is on a separate project that i have already added. How do I program it so that when I tap that button, it redirects me to another page that is of a different project but the same solution?

the code i used is:

`App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506731/how-to-redirect-to-a-page-which-exists-in-specif-project-to-another-page-in-othe?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TargetProjectName;/TargetPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is in a different assembly, you need to specify the name of that assembly.
Suppose your other project is called Assembly2. Then you navigate URI would be:

```
App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Assembly2;component/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```